# Starting a python script at boot - Raspbian

Tags: python, linux, arm, raspberry-pi, init.d

I have a python script. This script is essentially my own desktop/UI. However, I would like to replace the default Raspbian (Raspberry Pi linux distro) desktop enviroment with my own version. How would I go about:

1. Disabling the default desktop and
2. Launching my python script (fullscreen) at startup?

This is on the Raspberry Pi running a modified version of debian linux.

(Edit: I tried making a startup script in the /etc/init.d directory, and added it to chmod, but I still can't seem to get it to start up. The script contained the normal .sh stuff, but also contained the python command that opened the script in my designated directory.)

Comment: You might want to post this question in Server Fault instead of Stack Overflow: it has more to do with configuring your server than with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah bah, let's just give a quick answer.

After creating a script in `/etc/init.d`, you need to add a soft-link to the directory `/etc/rc2.d`, such as `sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/<your script> /etc/rc2.d/S99<your script>`. Assuming, of course, that you run runlevel 2. You can check that with the command `runlevel`.

The `S` means the script is 'started', the number determines the order in which processes are started.

You will also want to remove the entry from rc2.d that starts the graphical environment. What command that is depends on how your pi is configured.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! However, now once I get past a certain part of my script, my mouse won't move anymore. Is this due to me not having a window manager and running my script directly from the commandline? (The script uses Pygame and Python 2)

Comment: Hi user2548787, glad you found my post useful!

If the mouse moves at the beginning of the script and stops at some point, this is probably *not* due to the lack of a window manager. That only manages windows, not the mouse.

Is the CPU load very large? You can check that with the `top` command. 100% CPU load is one reason a mouse could stop moving.